# Reading JSON file with different object

Tags: java, json

I am learning java, I am using some API with the below json as an input.

My JSON file contains a different array of objects for example: an array of products and an array of facets.

How to read each product object and add to List.

Below is the json file which I'm using as an input to my code.

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": "3419105",
      "type": "product",
      "reviews": 91,
      "price": {
        "was": "",
        "then1": "",
        "now": "40.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "facets": [
    {
      "tooltip": "",
      "details": [
        {
          "facetId": "jkghjhhj",
          "isSelected": "false",
          "seoUrlParts": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tooltip": "",
      "details": [
        {
           "facetId": "jkghjhhjfa",
          "isSelected": "true",
          "seoUrlParts": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "crumbs": [
    {
      "type": "CATALOGUE",
      "displayName": "Women",
    }
  ],
  "dynamicBannerId": ""
  "triggeredRules": {
    "seo": "sdhskjhfksd"
  },
  "endecaCanonical": "/women/womens-clothing-nch/womens-dresses/_/N-flw"
}
```

Below is the code I have used

```
    String sURL = "some URL";
            URL url = new URL(sURL);
            URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
            request.connect();

            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
            JsonObject root = (JsonObject) jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            JsonArray jsonObject = root.getAsJsonArray();
```

I am able to get JSONObject, but later on, I'm not able to convert it to an array.
Any ideas on how I can solve this, read Products and facets, using Java 1.8?

Comment: which library are you using ?

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonParser

Comment: You are currently querying the root of your json, which is a JSONObject. You have to name the field containing your JSONArray like `root.getAsJsonArray('products')`